# Weak limit of random variable sequence

Tags: probability-limit-theorems

Suppose $\{X_i,i\ge1\}$ is a real-valued random variable sequence. Under what condition, there exists an another random variable $X$ such that $X_n\overset{d}{\to}X$. The notation $d$ means converge in distribution.

Comment: The definition seems to be the most useful condition.

Comment: @ Michael Could you explain it more specifically?

Comment: Perhaps you can state the definition of that type of convergence and then develop a few examples. That will give you more insight.

Comment: @ttkdm Suppose I ask the same question about a sequence of real numbers.. What would be your answer? Won't you just write down the defintion of convergence?